# Switching a user using "su" gives me only the $ prompt

Tags: bash, ubuntu, users, su

I'm using Ubuntu 19 and I created a few users already. On the latest user I created and tried to do a:

su userx

I login with only the $ prompt, but when I type "bash" as that user I get: **userx@myhost:**

My other users all login as user@myhost. Why is that user going directly to $ prompt? Also none of my paths work it seems. When I type **ll** it doesnt work until I type "bash".

Comment: check the use of the `-` operator, so you would do `su - userx` which should then spawn a normal login type session, which would source the various config files and set the `$PS1` (prompt) and `$PATH`, restore any aliases (your `ll`) etc.

Comment: why do my other users not have this issue when i do a su?

Comment: It depends on how you/they configured their startup files: read [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Comment: same issue actually even with su - http://prntscr.com/om4mt5

Comment: What is the user's login shell according to `getent passwd userx`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very likely that you did not set a login shell for the user when you created them, causing `su` to default to `/bin/sh`. As noted in `man su`:

> ```
>        The invoked shell is chosen from (highest priority first):
>
>            The shell specified with --shell.
>
>            If --preserve-environment is used, the shell specified by the
>            $SHELL environment variable.
>
>            The shell indicated in the /etc/passwd entry for the target
>            user.
>
>            /bin/sh if a shell could not be found by any above method.
> ```

Using adduser instead of useradd makes this process easier.

If there is no login shell listed next to the user in /etc/passwd, that would confirm that this is the issue.

You can fix this by running `usermod -s /bin/bash <username>`

Comment: yes. thank you. that works!

Comment: userx can change it herself with chsh /bin/bash